# convert hsla to rgba via jquery with jquery ui slider

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, uislider, rgba

I Am new to jquery ui. I recently doing a project in which I have some jquery ui sliders for hsla color picker. I have a slider with max value 360(hsla hue). I want to convert hsla to rgba. I searched on the web and I found some solutions for converting hsla to rgba. But I didn't know how to use them with slider value. So I decided that I will create new one and I got the pattern to convert hsla to rgba.

 The pattern is:

 when hsla hue value =0 rgba looks like : rgba(255, 0, 0 ,1). When hsla hue value =60 rgba looks like : rgba(255, 255, 0 ,1). That means, I need to change the rgba,s g(green) value from 0 to 255 with in hsla,s hue slider value between 0 to 60. Now, I am giving full list of hsla value = how much rgba,s value should be:


1 = rgba(255, 4, 0 ,1)
2 = rgba(255, 9, 0 ,1)
3 = rgba(255, 13, 0 ,1)
4 = rgba(255, 17, 0 ,1)
5 = rgba(255, 21, 0 ,1)
6 = rgba(255, 26, 0 ,1)
7 = rgba(255, 30, 0 ,1)
8 = rgba(255, 34, 0 ,1)
9 = rgba(255, 38, 0 ,1)
10 = rgba(255, 43, 0 ,1)
11 = rgba(255, 47, 0 ,1)
12 = rgba(255, 51, 0 ,1)
13 = rgba(255, 55, 0 ,1)
14 = rgba(255, 60, 0 ,1)
15 = rgba(255, 64, 0 ,1)
16 = rgba(255, 68, 0 ,1)
17 = rgba(255, 72, 0 ,1)
18 = rgba(255, 77, 0 ,1)
19 = rgba(255, 81, 0 ,1)
20 = rgba(255, 85, 0 ,1)
21 = rgba(255, 89, 0 ,1)
22 = rgba(255, 94, 0 ,1)
23 = rgba(255, 98, 0 ,1)
24 = rgba(255, 102, 0 ,1)
25 = rgba(255, 106, 0 ,1)
26 = rgba(255, 110, 0 ,1)
27 = rgba(255, 115, 0 ,1)
28 = rgba(255, 119, 0 ,1)
29 = rgba(255, 123, 0 ,1)
30 = rgba(255, 128, 0 ,1)
31 = rgba(255, 132, 0 ,1)
32 = rgba(255, 136, 0 ,1)
33 = rgba(255, 140, 0 ,1)
34 = rgba(255, 145, 0 ,1)
35 = rgba(255, 149, 0 ,1)
36 = rgba(255, 153, 0 ,1)
37 = rgba(255, 157, 0 ,1)
38 = rgba(255, 162, 0 ,1)
39 = rgba(255, 166, 0 ,1)
40 = rgba(255, 170, 0 ,1)
41 = rgba(255, 174, 0 ,1)
42 = rgba(255, 179, 0 ,1)
43 = rgba(255, 183, 0 ,1)
44 = rgba(255, 187, 0 ,1)
45 = rgba(255, 191, 0 ,1)
46 = rgba(255, 195, 0 ,1)
47 = rgba(255, 200, 0 ,1)
48 = rgba(255, 204, 0 ,1)
49 = rgba(255, 208, 0 ,1)
50 = rgba(255, 213, 0 ,1)
51 = rgba(255, 217, 0 ,1)
52 = rgba(255, 221, 0 ,1)
53 = rgba(255, 225, 0 ,1)
54 = rgba(255, 229, 0 ,1)
55 = rgba(255, 234, 0 ,1)
56 = rgba(255, 238, 0 ,1)
57 = rgba(255, 242, 0 ,1)
58 = rgba(255, 247, 0 ,1)
59 = rgba(255, 251, 0 ,1)
60 = rgba(255, 255, 0 ,1)

**[here](http://hslpicker.com/)** I found what I want. but I can't understand what is happening on the source code for converting hsla to rgba.


Here is my codes on **[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/shohidulpaltan/gchs3q9a/2/)**

```
$( "#range-slider" ).slider({
range:false,
min: 0,
max: 360,
value: 0,
step: 1,
slide: function( event, ui ) {
    var num = ui.value;
    $('.hsla-code').text("hsla(" + num + ", 100%, 50%, 1)");
    if (num < 61) {
        var rgba = "rgba(255, "+ num * 4 + ", 0, 1)";
        $('.header').css({
            background: rgba
        });
        $('.code').text(rgba);
    } else if (num < 121) {
        var nua = num - 60;
        var nub = nua * 4;
        var red =  255 - nub;
        var rgba = "rgba("+ red +", 255, 0, 1)";
        $('.header').css({
            background: rgba
        });
        $('.code').text(rgba);
    } else if (num < 181) {
        var nua = num - 120;
        var blue = nua * 4;
        var rgba = "rgba(0, 255, " + blue + ", 1)";
        $('.header').css({
            background: rgba
        });
        $('.code').text(rgba);
    } else if (num < 241) {
        var nua = num - 180;
        var nub = nua * 4;
        var green =  255 - nub;
        var rgba = "rgba(0, " + green + ", 255, 1)";
        $('.header').css({
            background: rgba
        });
        $('.code').text(rgba);
    } else if (num < 301) {
        var nua = num - 240;
        var red = nua * 4;
        var rgba = "rgba("+ red +", 0, 255, 1)";
        $('.header').css({
            background: rgba
        });
        $('.code').text(rgba);
    } else if (num < 361) {
        var nua = num - 300;
        var nub = nua * 4;
        var blue = 255 - nub;
        var rgba = "rgba(255, 0, "+ blue +", 1)";
        $('.header').css({
            background: rgba
        });
        $('.code').text(rgba);
    }
}
});
```

Comment: Your fiddle appears to work. It is not clear what is not working for you or what you're trying to accomplish. Please clarify further.

Comment: Also, I would look at their source: https://github.com/imathis/hsl-picker/

Comment: that's not accurate value for rgb. This is also not the correct algorithm to convert hsla to rgba and that's only hsla hue converted to rgba. I need correct algorithm to convert hsla to rgba.

Comment: w3 school also use the same algorithm like hslpicker.com. here is the [page](http://www.w3schools.com/colors/colors_hsl.asp)

Comment: I helped someone with a function like this: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/9nkc7sd6/ Could be adapted to HSLA with ease since you're not using the Alpha channel.

Comment: can you help me with this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/shohidulpaltan/bvamfvq0/1/). This codes are adapted from w3 school javascript.

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the W3Schools example, they use the following Functions to convert HSL to RGB:

```
function hslToRgb(hue, sat, light) {
    var t1, t2, r, g, b;
    hue = hue / 60;        
    if ( light <= 0.5 ) {
        t2 = light * (sat + 1);
    } else {
        t2 = light + sat - (light * sat);
    }
    t1 = light * 2 - t2;
    r = hueToRgb(t1, t2, hue + 2) * 255;
    g = hueToRgb(t1, t2, hue) * 255;
    b = hueToRgb(t1, t2, hue - 2) * 255;
    return {r : r, g : g, b : b};
}

function hueToRgb(t1, t2, hue) {
    if (hue < 0) hue += 6;
    if (hue >= 6) hue -= 6;
    if (hue < 1) return (t2 - t1) * hue + t1;
    else if(hue < 3) return t2;
    else if(hue < 4) return (t2 - t1) * (4 - hue) + t1;
    else return t1;
}
```

In your fiddle, you're adjusting the Hue from 0 to 360 using the slider. Here is my working example:

https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/q208xrrL/1/

**JQuery**

```
function hslToRgb(hue, sat, light) {
  var t1, t2, r, g, b;
  hue = hue / 60;
  if (light <= 0.5) {
    t2 = light * (sat + 1);
  } else {
    t2 = light + sat - (light * sat);
  }
  t1 = light * 2 - t2;
  r = hueToRgb(t1, t2, hue + 2) * 255;
  g = hueToRgb(t1, t2, hue) * 255;
  b = hueToRgb(t1, t2, hue - 2) * 255;
  return {
    r: Math.floor(r),
    g: Math.floor(g),
    b: Math.floor(b)
  };
}

function hueToRgb(t1, t2, hue) {
  if (hue < 0) hue += 6;
  if (hue >= 6) hue -= 6;
  if (hue < 1) return (t2 - t1) * hue + t1;
  else if (hue < 3) return t2;
  else if (hue < 4) return (t2 - t1) * (4 - hue) + t1;
  else return t1;
}

$("#range-slider").slider({
  range: false,
  min: 0,
  max: 360,
  value: 0,
  step: 1,
  slide: function(event, ui) {
    var hue = ui.value;
    var rgb = hslToRgb(hue, 1, .5);
    var rgba = "rgba(" + rgb.r + ", " + rgb.g + ", " + rgb.b + ", 1)";
    $('.header').css({
      background: rgba
    });
    $('.code').text(rgba);
    $('.hsla-code').text("hsla(" + hue + ", 100%, 50%, 1)");
  }
});
```

The Hue value should be from 0 to 360. Sat., Light, and Alpha use 0.0 to 1.0 (0 to 100 %). So when you use it, pass a value like `hslToRgb(100, 1, .5);`. If you decide to make 3 or 4 sliders, this will be important.

Comment: Thanks @Twisty for your help!

Comment: Thank you ,Thank you, Thank you very much @Twisty. I was trying to do this! Again a big thank you.

Comment: You can always show your thanks with upvotes ;) You're welcome.